# AngularJS ng-repeat filter, function over object property

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I am looking for a way to check for each movie if the movie has the category which is selected. Movies is an array which contains objects, those objects have some properties, like you can see in the code below. The categories property is a array of categories where the movie is in. Now there is a variable selectedCategories where the current selected category is stored in.

I don't want to use custom filters, because I think it has te be possible with this one, I just can't quite get it. In the javascript function there can't be changed too much either.

If the return of hasSelectedCategory is true, then it has to execute the block, if false not.

Thanks in advance.

```
//in the javascript file
scope.hasSelectedCategory = function(categories){
    var hasCategory = false;
    if (categories.indexOf(scope.selectedCategory) !== -1){
        hasCategory = true;
    }
    return hasCategory;
};
//in the html file
<div class="movieListItem {{listItemView}}" ng-repeat="movie in movies | filter:{hasSelectedCategory(categories): true}">
    <h4>{{movie.title}}</h4>
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{{movie.youtubeId}}?rel=0&autoplay=1"> 
    <img ng-src="{{findPosterSource(movie)}}" class="poster"> </a>
    <p ng-hide="listItemView === 'grid'">
        {{movie.description}}
    </p>
    <div class="categories" >
        <span ng-repeat="category in movie.categories"> <a ng-href="#">{{category}}</a> </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the filter like this:

```
ng-repeat="movie in movies | filter:hasSelectedCategory"
```

The `hasSelectedCategory` function will be invoked for each `movie` in the `movies` list. In order to filter by selected categories you can use a function like this:

```
$scope.hasSelectedCategory = function(movie) {
  var hasCategory = false;
  angular.forEach($scope.selectedCategories, function(selectedCategory) {
    if (!hasCategory && movie.categories.indexOf(selectedCategory) !== -1) {
      hasCategory = true;
    }
  });
  return hasCategory;
};
```

**[Demo (plunker)](http://plnkr.co/edit/UDlMnKYK4TFvSFlioqMJ?p=preview)**